# Rails: remote form with conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using `_form` both in `index` and `edit`. The problem is that, in `index`, it's a remote form, and in `edit`, I want it to be an ordinary form.

Perhaps something like

```
= form_for post, remote: true if params[:action] != 'edit' , html: { class: 'post-form' } do |f|
```

How can I do that?

Comment: define `form_for` in index and edit page only, and internal body of form in `_form` page..I have tried something like this before..hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different syntax:

```
= form_for post, remote: (action_name == 'index'), html: { class: 'post-form' } do |f|
```

You just want either `remote: true` or `remote: false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I end up with:
When calling

```
= render 'posts/form', post: @post, remote_control: false
```

And in `_form`

```
- remote_control = true if remote_control.nil?
= form_for post, remote: remote_control , html: { class: 'post-form' } do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
= form_for post, ({ remote: true } if params[:action] == 'edit') do |f|
```